# Syntax Error while trying to start a Python script with nohup

Tags: python, ubuntu, nohup

I want to run a Python3 Script on my Ubuntu Server 24/7.
I read that this is possible with `nohup`.
So I did the following command to start the Script:
`nohup python3 launcher.py &`
After that, I will get an Syntax Error in `nohup.out` which contains the following:

```
  File "launcher.py", line 22
    async def on_ready():
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

But the thing is, if I start the script via `python3 launcher.py` i will not get an Syntax Error.
Im working on a Discord Bot so Im using Discord.py.

Can someone explain me, why i get an Syntax Error when open the script with `nohup` ?

Because someone asked for the Code here is it:

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    def longestWord(sentence):
        """
            Get's the longest word in a string
                Example: longestWord(String1 + " " + String2)
            and for multiple Strings:
                Example 2: longestWord(String1 + " " + String2 + " " + String3)
        """
        longest = 0
        word = ''
        for i in sentence.split():
            if len(i) > longest:
                word = i
                longest = len(i)
        return word

    length = len(longestWord(client.user.name + " " + client.user.id)) + 10
    print("#".center(length,"#"))
    print("## Bot Online! ".ljust(length, "#"))
    print("## Name: {} ".format(client.user.name).ljust(length, "#"))
    print("## ID: {} ".format(client.user.id).ljust(length, "#"))
    print("#".center(length, "#"))
    print("\n")
    await client.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name='Phase: In Developement'))
```

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: It seems you ran python version under 3.5, which doesn't support async syntax.

Comment: Thats the point. I run `nohup python3` I have checked the version of Python and it's right. As I said if I open the script without `nohup` it works. Just with `nohup` i will get the Syntax Error. @Goralight I will edit the Question, gimme a sec.

Comment: `python3` is just a generic version 3. It might be an earlier version or a later version. If you do `python3 --version` what do you get then?

Comment: you could disprove hallazzang's theory by doing sys.stderr.write(sys.version). Perhaps there's 2 competing versions of python3 installed?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I will get `Python 3.5.2` @jambox what do you mean exactly ? Btw. even if i type only `python3` which will open the Python shell. I also get `Python 3.5.2`.

Comment: Find out the full path to python 3.5.2, e.g. using `which python3`, then use the *full path* with `nohup`, e.g. `nohup /usr/local/bin/python3.5` or similar.

Comment: Hm with `python3 -m site` i find out that python3 has some paths : `/usr/lib/python35.zip`, `/usr/lib/python3.5`, `/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu`, `/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload`, `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages`, `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`. And if I run `sudo nohup /usr/lib/python3.5 launcher.py &` I get an `Permission denied`.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and I used `nohup python3 myscript.py >> file.log &` instead of `nohup python myscript.py >> file.log &` and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really answered my Question but. I used `screen` now to open the Python Script in the Background.

1. Typed `screen` to start a new session.
2. Opened my Directory where my Bot is located
3. Typed `python3 launcher.py` to start the script with normal Python3

It works.